# Should *.lps files be included in version control or ignored?

Tags: delphi, version-control, lazarus, fpc

Lazarus generates 3 file types for projects - *.lpr, *.lpi and *.lps. The first 2 files are necessary.

Should I keep *.lps files in version control system or should I include *.lps files in global ignore list?

Comment: [`Documentation`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Project_Options#Save_session_information_in) says that the .lps file is useful if the .lpi file is under version control.

Comment: If only Delphi stored the active project target/arch in a separate file .....

Comment: @LURD yes, it is some 'private' file, so excluding .lps from version control is useful as it will keep my fellow developers file untouched ... btw other programming IDEs simple use a 'private' folder or filename/extension to give a hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, no if you are not sharing the projects.  Due to the [FAQ](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Faq), the lps files are "Lazarus Program Session - Personal data like cursor positions, source editor files, personal build modes. stored in XML".

Comment: IOW, it's the equivalent of an *.dsk?

Comment: I also think so but still keep *.lps in version control system because no documentation states that *.lps can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This old, but as I am starting with use hg, I had the same question.

It seems best to NOT store .lps file in version control systems.

References:

- http://wiki.freepascal.org/File_extensions
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Lazarus.gitignore

(Also wiki.freepascal.org/file_types and forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=9298.0)